# Разное значение UITextField каждый день

Tags: xcode

Доброго времени суток. Я хочу что бы мое приложение показывал время восхода и захода солнца в каждый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно в заданную дату изменить значение UITextField.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример вашего кода, объясните что у вас вызывает затруднения. Или вы просто хотите получить готовое решение?. Как задать вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @stas0k Я хочу направление показали хотя бы. Мой код не работает и он умеет каждый день одно и тоже

Comment: Тем не менее, стоит привести ваш код, пусть даже он и нерабочий. Таким образом вы получите более точную рекомендацию, возможно увидите нечто, что избавит вас от новых вопросов и даст возможность понять, где вы идёте не опираясь на best practice. Ничего стыдного в неработающем коде нет.

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko   Чтоб приложение вывела текст на экран в заданный день... Хотя бы это для начала.. А потом и разные тексты для каждого дня...

Comment: `if(self.targetDate == [NSDate date]) {self.textField.text = @"text";}`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko а нужную мне дату куда и как писать ?

Comment: объясните нормально что у вас не получается. вам надо при входе в приложение показать восход для текущей даты. 1) узнать текущую дату 2) запросить с сервера или с локальной базы восход 3) показать его в text field 4) при переходе приложения из бэкграунда в активное состояние повторить. что вызывает затруднение?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko  Все правильно. Мне же нужно сравнить текущую дату с базой который я занесу  (я не получаю его с сервера мне нужно чтоб время для каждого дня было внесено в приложение). Но я не могу элементарно, например: сделать так чтоб когда наступит 3 января на экран появился надпись 7:15... Имеется в виду даже для одного дня... Покажите как задать дату и сделать так чтоб когда наступит эта дата в приложении был надпись 7:15.... Спасибо большое, вы делаете большую помощь для новичка как я!

Comment: так вы так в вопросе и напишите - как сравнить заданную дату с текущей

Answer (score 1):

в интернетах предлагают две даты сравнивать так

```
- (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date1 otherDay:(NSDate*)date2 {
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date2];

return [comp1 day]   == [comp2 day] &&
[comp1 month] == [comp2 month] &&
[comp1 year]  == [comp2 year];
}
```

Comment: Теперь я столкнулся с другой проблемой. Если приложение не закрыто а находится в фоновом режиме, текст для следующего дня не обновляется... Если закрыть полностью и открыть тогда показывает все правильно... как можно решить ? СПАСИБО!